# Need to update a new password in a text file

Tags: linux, shell

I have some 100 of files where i need to update a new passwords according to a different users in different location files in a linux server.

​So, Is there any common shell script to update from old password to new password according to a user names.

Please find the content of the file is given below "Resource driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc4.jdbc.sysdert" name="jdbc/ryr_ined" type="sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql:xyz.com:1025/weare" username="xyz" password="abcd" autoCommit="false" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="20000"" And "Resource name="Tkmool" username="weare" password="abcd" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" "

Thank you for your help on this.

Comment: please give more info. what is the format of the files? is it enough to just replace one string with the other? or does the script have to do more complex checking? for example , only replace "joe" but not "joey"; or only replace the name if it comes after "password=".

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Files format are .pl, .txt and .conf etc., and script would find provided user name and location of the file and next to user name field called "password = " need to change from old password to new password.

Comment: How do you specify the new password and matching user name? As parameters?

Comment: If you have more details relating to your question, you should edit the question to improve its quality. If relevant details are buried in the comments, users may not see them – and you’re decreasing your chances of getting good answers. See also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .

Comment: with format of the files i did not mean their file-type, but how the text inside the files looks. give examples please (that works better then explaining it with words)

Comment: Thanks again Hoijui... Please find the content of the file is given below "<Resource
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc4.jdbc.sysdert"
      name="jdbc/ryr_ined"
      type="sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:mysql:xyz.com:1025/weare"
      username="xyz"
      password="abcd"
      autoCommit="false"
      maxActive="20"
      maxIdle="10"
      maxWait="20000"/>" And "<Resource name="Tkmool" username="weare" password="abcd" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" />".

Comment: As you can see, formatting in comments gets completely screwed up.  As Anthony asked you above, please edit this information into the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

This what you are looking for?

```
read -p "path (eg. *.conf will match a.conf)?" path
read -p "username?" username
read -p "new password?" password 
find $path -exec sed -r "s/(username="${username}".*password=)\w*/\1"${password}"/g" \{} >temporaryPasswordFile.tmp \; -exec mv temporaryPasswordFile.tmp \{} \;
```

requires that there are no files named temporaryPasswordFile.tmp present.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and follwoing error i am getting [root@Centos-Six ~]# sh -x repasswrod.sh
+ read -p /root/server.xml path
/root/server.xml
+ read -p cpgpapyr username
cpgpapyr
+ read -p abcdefgh password
abcdefgh
+ find -exec sed -r 's/(username=.*password=)\w*/\1/g' '{}' ';' -exec mv temporaryPasswordFile.tmp '{}' ';'
sed: read error on .: Is a directory
sed: read error on ./.gstreamer-0.10: Is a directory

sed: read error on ./.nautilus: Is a directory
mv: cannot stat `temporaryPasswordFile.tmp': No such file or directory

Comment: Um, I have a hard time reading/understanding the error message. But it looks somewhat like you are accessing parts of your disk that is inaccessible for some reason. What happens if you run the script as root?

Comment: Can find access the file at all? sudo find /root/server.xml -exec stat \{} \;

Comment: No, its giving me some annoying error i can not understanding that and all i am thinking is that why user password is not changing...

Comment: Command is find "/root/server.xml -exec stat \{} \;" and binary error while executing above command.

Comment: Try a different approach: copy your server.xml file to your home directory. chmod it to 0777. and then run the script on it to see if it works. I suspect there is some access problem behind it all. Oh, and I just realized that there are quotation marks around the password. To handle this replace the last line with: find $path -exec sed -r "s/(username="${username}".*password=\")\w*/\1"${password}"/g" \{} >temporaryPasswordFile.tmp \; -exec mv temporaryPasswordFile.tmp \{} \; I added \w.

Comment: @rms_3792748: I am afraid I will have to throw in the towel, it is hard to fix things, when it is impossible to recreate the error on a local machine. I will follow the thread to see if anything pops up. Good luck!